# How to get a blurred CSS3 Gradient

Tags: css

How do I get a blurred CSS3 gradient in Safari? Gradient I'm using doesn't look well, It looks stripped instead of blurred. It looks very nice in Firefox though. I hope I explain fine. [image: enter code here]

There it is an image (safari left, firefox right). The line in the middle is my wallpaper.

[image: Again another]

Again another image from safari. Here is clearer the strips. (They are with different colors, cuz are from different pages, but the same code)

```
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.45))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80ffffff', endColorstr='#73000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a blur effect overlay in a layer above a gradient?

Comment: No, that's a good idea. I'll try it. @abiessu

Comment: @abiessu I'm not able to make it work in order to solve it.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some of the code you are using, and maybe even a screenshot of what you want (or what you see in Firefox) vs. what you are getting (what you see in Safari)?

Comment: @abiessu ok there it goes

Comment: I must be missing something... you're saying you see stripes in Safari?  Can you do a magnification-screenshot or something to make it more obvious?  I am not seeing striping in the left-hand part of the image shown.  Also, would you mind showing the CSS you are using as well?

Comment: Check your CSS against this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @abiessu yes, i've added my code and a higher size image.